# Problems with SaaS Hw4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in HW4 of SaaS from Edx.org. I have problems running cucumber with scenarios 2 and 3. When I try the web application, it works good in these two scenarios. But running cucumber, I get this output:

```
Scenario: find movie with same director                       #        features/search_movies_director.feature:22
Deprecated: please use #source_tags instead.
Given I am on the details page for "Star Wars"              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
When I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"              # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
Then I should be on the Similar Movies page for "Star Wars" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230
  No route matches {:action=>"director", :controller=>"movies"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
  ./features/support/paths.rb:20:in `path_to'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:233:in `/^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/'
  features/search_movies_director.feature:25:in `Then I should be on the Similar Movies page for "Star Wars"'
And I should see "THX-1138"                                 # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105
But I should not see "Blade Runner"                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:123

Scenario: can't find similar movies if we don't know director (sad path) # features/search_movies_director.feature:29
Deprecated: please use #source_tags instead.
Given I am on the details page for "Alien"                             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
Then I should not see "Ridley Scott"                                   # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:123
When I follow "Find Movies With Same Director"                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
Then I should be on the home page                                      # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230
  expected: "/movies"
       got: "/movies/3/director" (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:233:in `/^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/'
  features/search_movies_director.feature:33:in `Then I should be on the home page'
And I should see "'Alien' has no director info"                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105
```

In both cases, when I manually do this scenarios, the behaviour is the correct. ¿What is the problem?

Thanks

When I execute 'rake routes', I get:

```
director_movie GET    /movies/:id/director(.:format) {:action=>"director", :controller=>"movies"}
    movies GET    /movies(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
           POST   /movies(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movies"}
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movies"}
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
```

Here, I can see the route "director_movie GET    /movies/:id/director(.:format) {:action=>"director", :controller=>"movies"}", so I don't realise why the first scenario fails.

In the second one, it expected "/movies" and got "/movies/3/director". Here is the piece of code from the controller:

```
def director
 mov = Movie.find(params[:id])
 dir = mov.director
 if (dir == nil)
   flash[:notice] = "'#{mov.title}' has no director info"
   redirect_to movies_path
 else
   @movies = Movie.find_all_by_director(dir)
 end
end
```

But when I simulate the same steps manually, I see the flash message and get redirect to "/movies"... Why cucumber doesn't get the same?

Sorry for my english... and thank you!

Comment: and what produces that output?

Comment: This output comes from cucumber, the testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not checking that the director could be empty too. In that case the redirect to the home page don't take place and the scenario fails. In order to fixed this situation you need to check for nil OR empty:

```
 if (dir.nil? || dir.empty?)
   flash[:notice] = "'#{mov.title}' has no director info"
   redirect_to movies_path
 else
   @movies = Movie.find_all_by_director(dir)
 end
```